# NEVPNManager instance is showing nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, frameworks, nevpnmanager

I had created network manager by using the below code. but as soon the first line of call is run the manager is being nil so any other methods are getting not effected. Can Anyone let me know that what wrong thing I had done ?

```
        NEVPNManager *manager = [NEVPNManager sharedManager];

        NEVPNProtocolIPSec *p = [[NEVPNProtocolIPSec alloc] init];
        p.username = @"MYUSERNAME";
        p.passwordReference = [@"MYPW" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        p.serverAddress = @"[NetworkIP]";
        p.authenticationMethod = NEVPNIKEAuthenticationMethodSharedSecret;
        p.sharedSecretReference = [@"SharedSecretHashCode"  dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        [manager setProtocol:p];
        [manager setOnDemandEnabled:NO];
        [manager setLocalizedDescription:@"VIT VPN"];
         NSArray *array = [NSArray new];
        [manager setOnDemandRules: array];
         NSLog(@"Connection desciption: %@", manager.localizedDescription);
         NSLog(@"VPN status:  %li", (long)manager.connection.status);


         [manager saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            if(error) {
                NSLog(@"Save error: %@", error);
            }
         }];
```

"`manager`" is being nil . please help. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found Solution for my question for the `NEVPNManager` instances.

When using this to the app developer must need its related certificates in which The `APPID` has has enabled the `VPN Configuration & controls`. and this app must need to run in the device.

[image]

So the `NEVPNManager` will not be nil and it can be adapt from the shared instance of the device. (also this is from `NetworkExtension.framework` which is available for `iOS8` & higher devices)

May be this can help anyone who is having the same issue.

Comment: Will this certificate be signed or unsigned certificate?

Comment: @PiyushDubey That thing doesn't matter to it.

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this.

Comment: Can you please check this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31408358/ios-8-vpn-nevpnmanager-error-neconfigurationerrordomain-code-11-ipc-failed